# Sagemaker endpoint inference with third-party libraries

Tags: pytorch, endpoint, amazon-sagemaker, fast-ai

I'm trying to create an endpoint with custom libraries, particularly trying to install `fastai`.
Going over this [tutorial](https://course.fast.ai/deployment_amzn_sagemaker.html#setup-your-sagemaker-notebook-instance) which is apparently incomplete. Endpoint deployment was failing at health check because of the missing library.

This [doc](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using_pytorch.html#using-third-party-libraries) says I can pass a list of third-party libraries in `requirements.txt` file. The file should be in `code` folder inside the `model.tar.gz` archive. This actually lets me deploy the endpoint with no issues but still fails when running predictions: `Received server error (500) from model with message "No module named 'fastai'"`.

Using PyTorch 1.3.1 estimator.

Contents of the `requirements.txt` is just `fastai`.

Wondering what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking that tutorial, which covers both training and inference: 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/building-training-and-deploying-fastai-models-with-amazon-sagemaker/.